# LSI Raid 5 with 2 disks "not synced"

Tags: raid, raid5, synchronization, lsi

I have a system with a LSI 1064e SAS raid.

The system is not booting, and when I enter the raid configuration utility, It says, that has 2 disc "Not synced".

I didn't find the option to resync them, also I don't know if it is possible.

If the disk were bad, it will say "failed" or something Isn't it?

May I have lost information?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have lost it all - or at least some part of it. You can likely force the array online, but basically 2 discs are out of sync and Raid 5 can handle 1 disc. Ergo - bad data. how much.... depends on what was going on at the time of failure.

Now, if you lost data then no, you did not loose it because of the 2 discs out of sync. You lost it because of absolute ignorance of something any professional should know: RAID is not a replacement for backup.

As in: In a sensible setup, the lost data would be miniscule per definition because you would just get most stuff back from the last backup. Which may be quite short term (I know companies doing a backup every 15 minutes).

That said, technically you may be lucky and not have lost a lot. I would investigate why - likely write back caching on the discs and a power failure.... so you lost the dirty data on the disc caches.

Comment: I have backup, but is a large server, and recovering all from backup should take lot of time. If I can resync it (maybe with some looses), i can recover that looses from the backup.  The question is... Anyone knows how to force that array online?

Comment: YOu likely lost a little only.... but it depends also how the server got into that state (power failure vs. shutdown /reset).

Comment: I think the problem was a power failure, but in not working hours... but my problem is that raid card does not have an option to "force" the sync of the array... Any clue?

Comment: No. Not really. This is the risk you run with disc level write back.... got hit by that too... backups welcome. Adaptec user here, it has a force online option ;) I now deactivated write caching and offset the performance impact with a SSD write cache - which makes things a LOOOOT faster ;)